# How to resolve an Unauthorized response from my Angular app

Tags: c#, angular, .net-6.0, angular17

I am trying to implement windows auth in my .NET Core App and Angular.  This is what I have done so far.

These are my launchSettings.json

```
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": true,
  "anonymousAuthentication": false,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5045",
    "sslPort": 44321
  }
}
```

This is my update to Program.cs

```
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();

 builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
 {
     options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
 });

app.UseCors(options =>
{
    options.AllowAnyHeader();
    options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:5045");
    options.AllowAnyMethod();
    options.AllowCredentials();
});

 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

I added proxy.conf.js file to my Client App.  As you can see I am using localhost:5045 which is set in localSettings.json

```
const { env } = require('process');
const HttpsAgent = require('agentkeepalive').HttpsAgent;

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:5045';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: ["/api"],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    agent: new HttpsAgent({
      maxSockets: 100,
      keepAlive: true,
      maxFreeSockets: 10,
      keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
      timeout: 6000000,
      freeSocketTimeout: 90000
    }),
    onProxyRes: proxyRes => {
      const key = "www-authenticate";
      proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] &&
        proxyRes.headers[key].split(",");
    }
  }
]

const { env } = require('process');
const HttpsAgent = require('agentkeepalive').HttpsAgent;

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:5045';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: ["/api"],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    agent: new HttpsAgent({
      maxSockets: 100,
      keepAlive: true,
      maxFreeSockets: 10,
      keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
      timeout: 6000000,
      freeSocketTimeout: 90000
    }),
    onProxyRes: proxyRes => {
      const key = "www-authenticate";
      proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] &&
        proxyRes.headers[key].split(",");
    }
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

And I am still getting a 401 Unauthorized.  I ran the API endpoint directly through Swagger and I am getting a success with a windows pop up showing up.  This is the controller I am testing it on

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<DataController> _logger;

    public DataController(ILogger<DataController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetUserLogin")]
    public ActionResult<User> GetUserDataAuthenticated()
    {
        var result = new User()
        {
            Login = User.Identity!.Name!
        };

        _logger.LogInformation("Login name: {LoginName}", result.Login);

        return this.Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?